# Incrementing/Decrementing value without overdoing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I currently have 2 values x and y and I want x to be decremented/incremented by y until it gets to 0 without going over.

```
float x = 9;
float y = 4;

if (x != 0) {

    if (x > 0) { 
        x -= y; 
    }

    else if (x < 0) { 
        x += y; 
    }
}
```

If this was to run x would be subtracted by y 3 times leaving the value of x  at -2 in which the next frame it will run again and add y which will again go over.

Comment: What should happen if `x == 0` holds?

Comment: @Codor think of it as a point along an axis I want to go from X to 0 in steps of Y

Answer (score 0):

You could change the implementation as follows by introducing clipping at `0` after the subtraction or addition.

```
if (x != 0) {
    if (x > 0) { 
        x -= y;
        x = Math.Max(x, 0.0f);
    }
    else if (x < 0) { 
        x += y;
        x = Math.Min(x, 0.0f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using something like this :

```
if ( x != 0 )
{
    x = x < 0 ? Math.Min(x + y, 0) : Math.Max(x - y, 0);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but see that still has the problem I'm trying to avoid! I dont want it to over subtract or over add so instead of going to -3 I want it to land on 0 and not over

Comment: @Blukzen Okay that was misunderstanding from my side, fixed that issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly, but if you want **x to be decremented/incremented by y until it gets to 0 without going over**, this should do it:

```
for( ; x>=0; x = x - y);
x = x + y;
```

Answer (score 0):

This function will give you this results in comments, for wrong parameters it will avoid going to infinity and return X:

```
//[9, 4] = 1
//[-9, -4] = -1    
private static float Unnamed(float x, float y)
        {
            float tmp = x;
            float result = x;
            while (true)
            {
                tmp -= y;
                if (y > 0)
                {
                    if (tmp > 0 && tmp < x)
                        result = tmp;
                    else
                        break;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (tmp < 0 && tmp > x)
                        result = tmp;
                    else
                        break;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay so based on @Codor's answer I got this

```
private float Approach(float value, float targetValue, float step) {

        float result;

        if (value < targetValue) {
            result = Mathf.Min (value + step, targetValue);
        } else {
            result = Mathf.Max (value - step, targetValue);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

which worked fine and does exactly what I wanted and will never go past the target value. And then I came across an already built in function that does exactly what I wanted as well `Mathf.MoveTowards(value, targetValue, step)`.